# Ruby group_by in array of arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

My array is

```
fruits = [["apple", "Tue"], ["mango", "Mon"], ["apple", "Wed"], ["orange", "Tue"]]
```

The result I want to get is to Group by Fruit and the count

```
[["apple", 2], ["mango", 1], ["orange", 1]]
```

I have always worked with just a single array when I wanted to group elements, how to work with array of arrays?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
fruits.group_by {|(fruit, day)| fruit }.map {|fruit, match| [fruit, match.count] }
```

Comment: If anyone else is looking for the direct documentation: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by

Answer (score 8):

```
fruits = [["apple", "Tue"], ["mango", "Mon"], ["apple", "Wed"], ["orange", "Tue"]]
fruits.group_by(&:first).map{|k,v| [k,v.size]}
# => [["apple", 2], ["mango", 1], ["orange", 1]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Your example format looks a lot like a hash. If it's OK to have a hash, then you can do this.

```
count = Hash.new(0)
fruits.each { |f| count[f.first] += 1 }
# => {"apple"=>2, "mango"=>1, "orange"=>1}
```

Then you can just convert it to an array.

```
count.to_a
# => [["apple", 2], ["mango", 1], ["orange", 1]]
```

*EDIT*

As a side note, defining the hash as `Hash.new(0)` means that the default value is `0` instead of `nil`. This is how we get away with not defining any of the hash keys first.

*EDIT 2*

With Arup's suggestion this turns into

```
counts = fruits.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |f, h| h[f.first] += 1 }
```

Depends on your preferences. I find the first a little easier to read.

Comment: The way you are using your code,I would suggest go with `each_with_object`.

Comment: or `fruits.reduce(Hash.new(0)) {|count,f| count[f.first] += 1; count}.to_a`.

Comment: Don'y you love the `Hash.new(0)`! It's like the best Ruby thing I've found this month.

Comment: I keep forgetting about `each_with_object`.  I prefer it to `reduce/inject` here and in similar situations, because there is no need to return an object to the iterator, which probably also reduces bugs.

Answer (score 2):

Being late to the party, I find the hors d'oeuvres nearly gone.  Alas, I'm left with just a crumb:

```
f = fruits.map(&:first).sort
f.uniq.zip(f.chunk(&:dup).map(&:size)) # => [["apple", 2], ["mango", 2], ["orange", 2]]
  # => [["apple", 2], ["mango", 2], ["orange", 2]]
```

Had I been more punctual, I would have grabbed one of those yummy `group_by` tarts.